# What is the recommended diameter of the Idle Fuel Discharge Port?

Tags: fuel-system, carburetor, idle

My car is a 1987 Toyota Tercel DX Wagon 1452cc 2bl manual driven car. Carburetor of it is a Aisan 14120 Two Barrel carburetor.

I heard that the Idle Fuel Discharge Port size affects for the fuel efficiency of a car. There are upper port and a lower port in the primary barrel and a one in the secondary barrel.

What is the recommended diameter of the Idle Fuel Discharge Port (orifice) for upper and the lower discharge ports in the primary barrel and that in the secondary barrel?

Comment: You would do yourself a big favour if you got a workshop manual for your car.

Comment: I dont have this manual. It is the biggest problem I have. If someone who know those values and tell it that would be a help.